# Internet Explorer 8 HTML5 elements not being styled properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I have a problem with my website in Internet Explorer 8, it doesn't happen in the version I have personally, but my friend tried it and showed me a screenshot.

[image: http://puu.sh/6CM4c.jpg]

The website is www.mikkeljohannsen.com and you're able to see the code and everything on there too of course, so I'm guessing it'll just be easier that way.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You could use html5shiv (http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to assist with this...

Comment: Hi, the first thing you should know is that IExplorer 8 doesn't support html5 and is a little bit tricky. One useful page to check the CSS is http://caniuse.com/, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support many HTML5 elements like `article`, `section` and so on. You need to look at using something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which uses Javascript to emulate HTML5 elements in browsers that don't support them.